# open a text file via windows double click with ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm fairly new to Ruby, so please excuse me if my question is too basic...

I wrote a program that searches a text file for certain values. 
The way it works is that when I run the program from command line it asks for the file to search through. So I drag the file over to the command window and press Enter. The program takes over and does what it's supposed to... I also created an exe file using Ocra just so I don't have to run it from command line.

It works great, but I want to take it a step further. How can I modify my program to be able to double click the text file in Windows and have my program automatically open and do it's search?

Comment: Why are you double clicking the text file instead of the exe file?

Comment: I think whatever you are doing, if possible, is a feature of the command window, and has nothing to do with Ruby.

Comment: @Mike: because the text file is a different file in a different directory every time... I actually do CNC programming as well. Every CNC program that I write has Z-axis values that cannot be greater than -0.005 inch. If it is larger than I may damage the CNC machine... Up until now, after writing each CNC program, we manually searched the G-code for those Z-axis values. I made this ruby program that does it for us, but like I mentioned earlier it is a bit less than ideal to use. Sometimes it is faster to manually search Z-values than open my ruby program and drag the file there...